# mysql comma separate table column in a concat() or similar approach

Tags: mysql

```
Database Setup_Items
id     product
1      53,23,11,57


Database Product
id   name
53   product 53
23   product 23
11   product 11
57   product 57 etc etc etc
```

So I've got a database table  for Setup_Items (si) which combine multiple products into a group.  Then I've got a database table for Product (p) that stores all the product information.

**I'm using the following query** to get the information from the Product (p) table based on which Setup_Item (si) is selected

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,p.image
    FROM Setup_Items as si
    INNER JOIN Product as p ON si.products LIKE CONCAT(',', p.id, ',')
```

Heres my problem.  The following items are in the database...

```
Setup_Items.products = 53,23,11,57
```

**Current Results**

1. It is getting 9 results back...5, 3, 53, 2, 23, 1, 11, 7, 57
2. Its breaking the two digit numbers into both 2 digit and single
   digit unique numbers.

**Needed Results**

***I only need 4 results.  53, 23, 11, 57***

How do I need to write this query to get these results?

If there is a better method than concat() please let me know!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FIND_IN_SET:

```
    SELECT p.id, p.name 
    FROM Setup_Items as si
    INNER JOIN Product as p ON FIND_IN_SET(p.id, si.product)
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  I've never used find_in_set before; however, I've now used it about 20 times since you mentioned it. haha